# Error when creating an Activity in android

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I've a problem when I try to add a new activity to my Project with ADT 22.0.4.

The problem is with the file strings.xml as you can see in this screenshot. 
[image]

I'va update my ADT to see if the problem is solved but it's not. I also try to create an activity in an other projet and there isn't any problem...

Is there any one who had this and can help me to correct it ?

Comment: have You checked if Your Package name is doubled with another project? If yes, rename it. Have YOu tried to clean Your project?

Comment: what is the detail about

Comment: Opiatefuchs => There isn't any project with the same name. And I already try many times to clean it and nothing change

Comment: kevinhoo => detail is just a copy of wath is already in the screenshot (realy usefull detail ^^